# Find the density function of the sum $(X,X+Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, bivariate-distributions

**Problem**

I have to prove the following:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent continuous random variables with density function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. \
Prove that $(X,X+Y)$ is a continuous bivariate random variable with density function $f_{X,X+Y}(x,z)=f(x)f(z-x)$.

**My thoughts**

Look at $$\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant x,X+Y\leqslant z)=\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant x,Y\leqslant z-x)=\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}\int_{-\infty}^x f_{X,Y}(u,v)\,du\,dv.$$
Since $X$ en $Y$ are independent and have the same density function, we have $f_{X,Y}(u,v)=f(u)f(v)$, so
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}\int_{-\infty}^x f(u)f(v)\,du\,dv=\int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f(v)\left(\int_{-\infty}^x f(u)\,du\right)dv=\int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f(v)\,dv\cdot \int_{-\infty}^x f(u)\,du$$
Now I feel like I am very close, but we can't use the FTC since $f$ is not necessarily continuous (only right continuous). This might be a stupid question, but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: $\{X\leq x,X+Y\leq z\}\neq\{X\leq x, Y\leq z-x\}$ so you made a false start.

Comment: @drhab that's good to know :D

Comment: I will edit my answer and then undelete it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That would be great

Comment: Be careful not to get confused between cdf ($F_X(x)=P(X\le x)$) and pdf (density, $f_X(x)$ such that $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t) dt$). CDF's are those which are always right continuous; densities need not be continuous, in fact they're are not uniquely defined. But given a density, if it exists, the corresponding CDF is not only continuous, but also differentiable a.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\Pr(X\le x\ \&\ X+Y\le z) = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^{z\,-\,u} f_{X,\,Y} (u,v) \, dv \, du = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^{z-u}f(u)f(v) \, dv\,du
$$

For any particular value $u$ that the random variable $X$ can assume between $-\infty$ and the value $x$ being considered, the value of $X+Y = u+Y$ is $\le z$ precisely if $Y\le z-u.$

Next we have
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^{z\,-\,u} f(u) f(v) \, dv \, du = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^z f(u)f(v-u) \, dv\,du \\[10pt]
\text{because } & \int_{-\infty}^{z-u} f(v)\,dv = \int_{-\infty}^z f(v-u)\, du \text{ by routine substitution.} 
\end{align}
Then we will have
$$
\Pr(X\le x\ \&\ X+Y\le z) = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^z f(u) f(v-u) \,dv\,du
$$
and that implies that the function being integrated on the right side is the density of $(X,\,X+Y).$

Comment: But what about the false start comment by drhab? I don't understand it anymore, could you elaborate by posting a proof ?

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz : I've revised this. $\qquad$

Comment: The 'routine substitution' is the part that boggles me. Namely, you do the substitution $u=v+u$ on the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{z-u} f(v)\,dv$, which doesn't make sense? Could you explain further?

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz : You have $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{z-u} f(v)\,dv. $ Now let $w=v+u,$ so that $v=w-u$ and $\dfrac{dw}{dv} = 1,$ and so $dw = dv.$ As $v$ goes from $-\infty$ to $z-u,$ then $w$ goes from $-\infty$ to $z.$ So the integral becomes $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^z f(w-u) \, dw.$ And since $w$ is a bound variable, it can be freely renamed, so that for example, this last integral could be called $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^z f(r-u)\, dr$ or $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^z f(s-u) \, ds.$ Thus it is $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^z f(v-u) \, dv. \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

The continuity of $X+Y$ is obvious from that of $X$ and $Y$.  Let $g:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function.

In the second step, make a change of variables $z = x+y$.  Thanks to [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), changing order of integration is allowed.

\begin{align}
\Bbb{E}[g(X,X+Y)] &= \int_{\Bbb{R}^2} g(x,x+y) f_X(x) f_Y(y) \,dx\,dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,x+y) f_Y(y) \,dy \right) f_X(x) \,dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,z) f_Y(z-x) \,dz \right) f_X(x) \,dx \\
&= \int_{\Bbb{R}^2} g(x,z) f_X(x) f_Y(z-x) \,dx \,dz
\end{align}

Therefore, $(X,X+Y)$ has density $f_{X,X+Y}(x,z) = f_X(x) f_Y(z-x)$.

In particular, when $f_X = f_Y = f$, $f_{X,X+Y}(x,z) = f(x) f(z-x)$.

Comment: What is the reason to invoke the expected value ?

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz That's the [standard way of proving density](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167128/290189).  Take $g \equiv 1_A$ to recover $\Bbb{P}(A)$.